# Cannot use percent height in child DIV when the parent DIV has a min-height?

Tags: css, height

Here is the first example. This works fine. Here `.b` occupies 50% of the height of `.a`.

```css
.a {
  background: orange;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the second example. It is pretty much the same except that `min-height` is used to set the height of `.a` instead of using `height`.

```css
.a {
  background: orange;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

But in this second example, the blue box almost vanishes. It is not 50% the height of `.a` anymore. Why does this issue happen? How to fix it while using `min-height` for `.a`?

Answer (score 2):

Incredible I had never seen this case actually, the tricks I would see would be:

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 5px solid blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
```